# Transfering content from Portal to ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-portal, data-transfer

I am assisting a coworker with developing a Story Map for his organization.  He created all of his content, but mistakenly created and saved everything within his organizational Portal.  Although his content is ready to be shared, it needs to be in ArcGIS Online due to the URL format.  Our web content system does not support the URL provided by Portal.

Is there a way to transfer content from a Portal account to an ArcGIS Online account without using a python script or having to recreate the Story Map and associated content?

Answer (score 2):

If the data exists in both the Portal and Online environments in your organization, I believe you can use https://ago-assistant.esri.com/ and copy the JSON from one to another. I have used this to recreate webmaps across different development environments on our Portal.